# Are there any for-pay (commercial) but open source applications in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, open-source, commercial

I've recently decided to try not to support any proprietary software, and see how far I can go with Free software.

Despite this, I realize Free software costs money to make, and would be happy to pay for some. Is there any way to sort through the software in Ubuntu Software Center to find some, or if not, what applications are there are there? (Examples would be great)

Thanks!

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I appreciate Open Source and consider myself pro-open-source. However, where does the anti-proprietary attitude come from? What's wrong with the developer who put work into a program maintaining ownership of the software?

Comment: Allow me to point you to the GNU website: http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/philosophy.html
Essentially, proprietary software does less overall good than free (as in freedom) software. For example, users are unable to make changes they want, without begging the sole developer, and developers can't learn from the source code. Additionally, one has to put their full trust in the sole developer, because aside from reverse engineering, only the sole developer can really know what it is the program is doing. Despite this, I WANT to pay for free software, to support development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are such commercial applications. You can install them via Ubuntu software center.

Just Open Software Center, Click the down arrow after *All software* catagory and select *for purchase*.

Please note, not all of the softwares in this catagory is open source. Some are proprietary too. You can see the licence type by clicking the *more info* button beside the Apps name.

And some proprietary Apps are provided for $0.0 i.e free in cost.

**Example:** One example of such applications is **dupeGuru** which requires $10.0 but is open source. (BSD-Licence)

Comment: That's good to know! Do you know of any, specifically?

Comment: Yeah! This is the answer! (upvoted) Now... do you mind providing a list of applications or a link where to find such list? I am understanding that "paid" software is better supported and/or includes good improvements for software alternatives. I would like (in example) to find good alternatives for multimedia, audio/video production. Thank you!

Comment: but isn't this against the open source idea ?? I moved to linux because it is totally free. and I kept recommending Ubuntu to everyone since it is FREE. Now what am I going to say to my friends who converted to Ubuntu ?

Comment: Anwar, the page with commercial apps is indeed useful, but it's cumbersome to go through the hundred applications to check the license status.

Comment: @hnasarat One such application which requires $ but is open source is **dupeGuru**. Sorry, the still don't know a much better way to sort by licence type. Will update you shortly

Comment: @Anwar Thanks! Perfect example. Additionally, I'm looking for free as in Freedom, not as in no-cost.

Comment: @Suhaib Those apps are provided for those people who may need them. Ubuntu software center only shows them, but those aren't canonical supported. And of course, the Adobe Flash isn't open source and most of the codecs isn't open source at all. but I think, 99% people like to have them

Comment: @Suhaib you're right, one of the nice things about Ubuntu is that it's no-cost; however, you're falling for easily-confused terminology. Usually, when referring to open-source software, free is short for freedom, not no-cost. See this link (and the gnu.org website in general) for more info: http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html

Comment: Accepted. Thanks for the help, and example. If anyone has more examples I'd love to see more answers, or edits.